# how many ways can you make 9 "ones" or "zeros"

Tags: combinatorics

How many possibilities are there to create a 9-digit number from two digits: 0 and 1 (zero and one), i.e. how many ways can you arrange these two digits?

eg:
000000000

000000001

000010010

111101111

111000100

000011001

111110000

010101000

001101110

ect.

Is there any program that can create all possible combinations?
I will be grateful for your response.

Comment: What is your purpose: 1) counting them, they are $2^{9}=512$ 2) writing them down with a computer program : in this case, make a loop with an index i ranging from 0 to 512-1 and convert it into its **binary (base 2 numeration)** representation (there are functions for that, for example in Matlab, it is "num2base")

Answer (score 1):

For each digit you have two possibilities.
So this makes a total of $2^9$ possibilities.

As for generating all combinations, you just need to nest $9$ for loops.
For instance if you had to generate all $3$-digit-numbers with $0$ and $1$, you can do :

> for $i$ from $0$ to $1$ :
> ...for $j$ from $0$ to $1$ :
> ......for $k$ from $0$ to $1$ :
> .........return $\overline{ijk}$

Comment: Actually, you don't really *need* $9$ nested loops. There is a very simple algorithm to enumerate all $n$-tuples with elements in a given list, that doesn't require $n$ nested loops, but $2$.

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeArbaut Yes but that's the most intuitive way. Plus this doesn't change the complexity in our case. You can't do better than $O(2^n)$ since you need to print $2^n$ numbers. But of course if you want to implement it for a generic $n$ my algorithm is not relevant.

Answer (score 0):

It has already been explained that there are $p^n$ lists of length $n$ with arbitrary elements from an alphabet of length $p$. It's just an application of the [rule of product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_product). Let's see how to generate these lists.

The following Python function enumerates all $n$-tuples from the list $a$. This function (as well as all the alternatives below) is implemented as a Python generator, to allow looping on tuples without building the whole list. It's close enough to pseudocode to implement in another language if need be.

```
def tuples(a, n):
    m = len(a)
    u = [0] * n
    while True:
        yield tuple(a[i] for i in u)
        j = n - 1
        while j >= 0 and u[j] == m - 1:
            u[j] = 0
            j -= 1
        if j < 0:
            return
        u[j] += 1
```

For instance, for $4$ bits:

```
>>> list(tuples([0, 1], 4))
[(0, 0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 0, 1), (0, 0, 1, 0), (0, 0, 1, 1),
 (0, 1, 0, 0), (0, 1, 0, 1), (0, 1, 1, 0), (0, 1, 1, 1),
 (1, 0, 0, 0), (1, 0, 0, 1), (1, 0, 1, 0), (1, 0, 1, 1),
 (1, 1, 0, 0), (1, 1, 0, 1), (1, 1, 1, 0), (1, 1, 1, 1)]
```

For $9$ the output is to large to print here, but you get the length $2^9$ as expected:

```
>>> sum(1 for u in tuples([0, 1], 9))
512
```

---

Note that in Python, the same can be achieved with a builtin function:

```
import itertools
>>> list(itertools.product([0, 1], repeat=4))

[(0, 0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 0, 1), (0, 0, 1, 0), (0, 0, 1, 1),
 (0, 1, 0, 0), (0, 1, 0, 1), (0, 1, 1, 0), (0, 1, 1, 1),
 (1, 0, 0, 0), (1, 0, 0, 1), (1, 0, 1, 0), (1, 0, 1, 1),
 (1, 1, 0, 0), (1, 1, 0, 1), (1, 1, 1, 0), (1, 1, 1, 1)]
```

---

Since you are enumerating bit sequences, there is an even simpler algorithm: loop on all numbers between $0$ and $2^9-1$, and convert each in base $2$.

```
def bits(n):
    for p in range(1 << n):
        u = []
        for i in range(n):
            u.append(p & 1)
            p >>= 1
        yield tuple(u)
```

For instance:

```
>>> list(bits(4))
[(0, 0, 0, 0), (1, 0, 0, 0), (0, 1, 0, 0), (1, 1, 0, 0),
 (0, 0, 1, 0), (1, 0, 1, 0), (0, 1, 1, 0), (1, 1, 1, 0),
 (0, 0, 0, 1), (1, 0, 0, 1), (0, 1, 0, 1), (1, 1, 0, 1),
 (0, 0, 1, 1), (1, 0, 1, 1), (0, 1, 1, 1), (1, 1, 1, 1)]

>>> sum(1 for u in bits(9))
512
```

---

A simpler way still, using the builtin Python function to convert to binary.

```
def bits(n):
    m = 1 << n
    return (tuple(int(s) for s in bin(m + k)[3:]) for k in range(m))
```

For instance:

```
>>> list(bits(4))
[(0, 0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 0, 1), (0, 0, 1, 0), (0, 0, 1, 1),
 (0, 1, 0, 0), (0, 1, 0, 1), (0, 1, 1, 0), (0, 1, 1, 1),
 (1, 0, 0, 0), (1, 0, 0, 1), (1, 0, 1, 0), (1, 0, 1, 1),
 (1, 1, 0, 0), (1, 1, 0, 1), (1, 1, 1, 0), (1, 1, 1, 1)]

>>> sum(1 for u in bits(9))
512
```